# Method name expected

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I have to create a json file with an array inside in c# so this is my code but throws an exception:

```
Method name expected
```

before `new Dictionary<string, int>[2]();`

Have you got any suggestions?

```
int[] lung = results.ToArray();

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>[]> padre = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>[]>();
Dictionary<string, int>[] udemy = new Dictionary<string, int>[2]();
padre.Add("Lunghezza", udemy);
udemy[0].Add("attributo", lung[0]);
udemy[1].Add("attributo2", lung[1]);
string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(padre);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(js);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an exception rather than a compile-time error? Can you please provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: removing parenthesis at the end of the `new Dictionary<string, int>[2]();` will fix compile error.

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with JSON at all. It's always worth trying to minimize the number of concepts involved in a question before asking it - if you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, you can remove everything extraneous leaving *just* the problem...

Comment: Are you sure you need a dictionary that stores an array of dictionaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't how you construct an array;

```
new Dictionary<string, int>[2]()
```

You don't need the `()` at all - you're not calling a method or a constructor; you're creating an array instance. Just:

```
new Dictionary<string, int>[2]
```

You'll need to *populate* the array as well, of course, e.g.

```
udemy[0] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
udemy[1] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Using a simpler array type makes it easier to see the problem:

```
// Invalid
int[] x = new int[2]();

// Valid
int[] x = new int[2];
```

As a side note, a type of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>[]>` is pretty horrible - I would strongly encourage you to redesign that to use more meaningful types.

Comment: thanks, i know that it's horrible but i have to do a fast example, so if i don't use () it compiles but i can't add any things into the dictionary :( it throws an exception becouse the udemy dictionary is not an object. Do you know a different method to do that?

Comment: @GrazianoDimatteo: What do you mean by "I can't add any things into the dictionary"? You need to *create* the dictionaries first - you've currently just got the array. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] lung = results.ToArray();

    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>[]> padre = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>[]>();
    Dictionary<string, int>[] udemy = new Dictionary<string, int>[2]();
    // populate 
    udemy[0].Add("attributo", lung[0]);
    udemy[1].Add("attributo2", lung[1]);
    // then add
    padre.Add("Lunghezza", udemy);
    string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(padre);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(js);
```

Comment: This produces the same compile-time error. Furthermore you change the order but not the behaviour of the statements as `padre` will only contain the reference to `udemy`, so whenever changing the last also the content of the first will change as they reference the same instances.

Comment: i forgot to remove the brackets sorry !